# Access denied to website using with Selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I have a problem with even an open website using "webdriver Chrome". Only trying to open the website end with "Access denied" information and don't know why. Below is my code:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.lowes.com/login")
time.sleep(5)   
driver.find_element_by_id("Email").send_keys("teshooabood@gmail.com")
driver.find_element_by_id("Password").send_keys("Tz5PRZPeF@ytb3e\n")
```

Answer (score 0):

I feel like this is not a problem of your selenium script.

Navigating to https://www.lowes.com/ and clicking on `Sign in` -> `Sign in or create account` results in `403 Forbidden: Access denied` immediately. Same for directly navigating to https://www.lowes.com/login. I guess there is some bug in the webpage's code.